# How to install sklearn on a python shell created by a js file?

Tags: python, node.js, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a sentiment analysis script written in python from a js file. The python script runs fine from my terminal, but when I go to run it from the js file it throws an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/ml_models/sentiment_analysis_script.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have tried to install sklearn in the root folder, but it still is not working. This is the code that I currently have for my js file

```
let runPy = new Promise(function(success, nosuccess) {

  const { spawn } = require('child_process');
  const pyprog = spawn('/usr/bin/python3', ['sentiment_analysis_script.py', "my new puppy is so cute"]);


  pyprog.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("no success");
      nosuccess(data.toString());
  });

  pyprog.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("success");
      success(data.toString());
  });
});

runPy.then(function(fromRunpy) {
  console.log(fromRunpy);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

and the code from my python script

```
import pickle
import sys

# load the saved model and vectorizer from disk
with open('note_sentiment_analysis.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

with open('note_vectorizer.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    vectorizer = pickle.load(f)

# Get text input from the user
text = sys.argv[1]

# Preprocess the data
text = text.lower()
text = text.replace('[^\w\s]','')
text = text.replace('\d+','')
text = text.replace('\n',' ')
text = text.replace('\t',' ')

# Vectorize the text
vectorized_text = vectorizer.transform([text])

# Predict the sentiment using the model
prediction = model.predict(vectorized_text)[0]

# Get the probability estimates for each class
proba = model.predict_proba(vectorized_text)[0]

# Print the prediction and probability estimates
if prediction == 0:
    print("Negative sentiment with probability {:.2f}%".format(proba[0]*100))
else:
    print("Positive sentiment with probability {:.2f}%".format(proba[1]*100))
```

Would be very appreciative of any help that might let me run this python script and gather its output from a js file!

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that the 'sklearn' module is not installed in the Python environment that is used to execute the script. To install "sklearn" you can add the the bellow code at the end of your python script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["pip", "install", "scikit-learn"])
```

You can do it manually in the Python environment before running the JavaScript file. Open the terminal and in the directory containing the 'sentiment_analysis_scripy.py' just run pip install scikit-learn.